# Do I have to convert string to double when sorting an array of numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to sort an array in c++ whose elements are of the "string" type, but are supposed to be numbers (due to some other reasons I cannot store them as double numbers), like the following:

```
vector<string> a;

//assign a with some values, e.g. a=["5.1" "3.5" "1.4" "0.2"]

sort(a.begin(),a.end());
```

So my question is: do I need to convert each element in the vector from string to double before calling sort? How exactly does c++ sort an array like this and how precise it can be? Thanks!

Comment: The array will be sorted in lexical order, not numeric. You can provide your own comparator function with [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Convert the two parameters to `double` inside thatt function and return the result of the comparison.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ cant he just sort the strings? It looks like they all have same number of digits

Comment: @tobi303 This may turn out the wrong way quickly as soon the number of digits becomes arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> do I need to convert each element in the vector from `string` to `double` before calling `sort`?

This depends on the order that you would like to achieve, and on the numbers stored in the array. If all numbers have exactly one digit before the dot, you wouldn't see a difference; if some numbers have multi-digit whole part, your sort would be incorrect, because strings are alphabetized. For example, `"2.0"`, `"9.0"`, `"10.0"` would be sorted as follows:

```
"10.0", "2.0", "9.0"
```

As far as "before" in "before calling `sort`" is concerned, the conversion does not need to happen before sorting; you could perform it as you go if you use a custom comparison function:

```
sort(
    a.begin()
,   a.end()
,   [](const string &lhs, const string &rhs) -> bool { 
        return stod(lhs) < stod(rhs); 
    }
);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/9gsiLR)

Comment: You might be interested in the results of my test below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string n1 = "5.2";
string n2 = "10.1";
if (n1 < n2) {
    cout << "n1 is less" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "n2 is less" << endl;
}
```

The output is `n2 is less` because the character `'5'` is greater than the character `'1'`. This is what happens if you compare the strings directly.

Answer (score 1):

C++ converts each character of the string to ascii code, and then it orders by ascii order, so this doesn't work, u have to convert each string to a numerical type to order it properly.

Comment: Sigh. Blatant ASCII-ism. <g> There are encodings other than ASCII out there in the real world. Strings are compared lexicographically, according to the order for whatever encoding is in use.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of converting a string to a double is actually pretty high.

A naive approach to this sort is to compare on the predicate `stod(l) < stod(r)`.

As the following test shows, in situations where the vector to be sorted is large, it's actually worth performing the conversions once and sorting the converted vector.

Here is the optimised algorithm:

```
template<class Vector>
void sort_numeric_single_conversion(Vector& vec)
{
    auto first = vec.begin();
    auto last = vec.end();
    auto size = vec.size();

    using element = std::tuple<double, std::size_t>;
    std::vector<element> elements;
    elements.reserve(size);
    for (auto current = first ; current != last ; ++current)
    {
        elements.emplace_back(stod(*current), current - first);
    }
    std::sort(std::begin(elements), std::end(elements), [](auto& l, auto &r) {
        return std::get<double>(l) < std::get<double>(r);
    });

    Vector buffer;
    buffer.reserve(size);
    for(auto& elem : elements)
    {
        auto isource = std::get<std::size_t>(elem);
        buffer.push_back(std::move(vec[isource]));
    }
    vec = std::move(buffer);
}
```

And here's the test that argues for this approach (compiled on macbook pro with `-O3 -march=native`:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>


template<class Vector>
void sort_numeric_single_conversion(Vector& vec)
{
    auto first = vec.begin();
    auto last = vec.end();
    auto size = vec.size();

    using element = std::tuple<double, std::size_t>;
    std::vector<element> elements;
    elements.reserve(size);
    for (auto current = first ; current != last ; ++current)
    {
        elements.emplace_back(stod(*current), current - first);
    }
    std::sort(std::begin(elements), std::end(elements), [](auto& l, auto &r) {
        return std::get<double>(l) < std::get<double>(r);
    });

    Vector buffer;
    buffer.reserve(size);
    for(auto& elem : elements)
    {
        auto isource = std::get<std::size_t>(elem);
        buffer.push_back(std::move(vec[isource]));
    }
    vec = std::move(buffer);
}

template<class Vector>
void sort_numeric_naive(Vector& vec)
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto& l, auto& r) {
        return stod(l) < stod(r);
    });
}

std::vector<std::string> build_test_array(std::size_t size)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine eng(rd());
    auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(-1000000.0, 1000000.0);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(result), size, [&] {
        return std::to_string(dist(eng));
    });
    return result;
}

template<class F>
auto time(F f)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    auto then = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return then - now;
}

template<class Duration>
std::string to_ms(Duration d)
{
    auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(d);
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(7) << ms.count() << "ms";
    return ss.str();

}

int main()
{
    for(auto size : { 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000 })
    {
        auto v1 = build_test_array(size);
        auto v2 = v1;

        auto t1 = time([&] { sort_numeric_single_conversion(v1); });
        auto t2 = time([&] { sort_numeric_naive(v2); });

        std::cout << "size: " << std::setw(7) << size << " single: " << to_ms(t1) << ", naive: " << to_ms(t2) << std::endl;
    }

}
```

typical results:

```
size:      10 single:       0ms, naive:       0ms
size:     100 single:       0ms, naive:       0ms
size:    1000 single:       0ms, naive:       1ms
size:   10000 single:       1ms, naive:      17ms
size:  100000 single:      18ms, naive:     235ms
size: 1000000 single:     210ms, naive:    2797ms
size: 10000000 single:    2397ms, naive:   33120ms
```